# Convert a .CSV file into .XML

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a .csv file with 8 column pairs that looks like this:

```
level_1,level_1_desc, level_2, level_2_desc, level_3, level_3_desc, level_4,level_4_desc
```

This represents a hierarchical or tree structure, where:

```
- Level 1
    - Level 2
        - Level 3
            - Level 4
```

I can read the contents of the .csv file and assign them to a dictionary variable in python just fine, just like a Dictionary.

I understand the basics of creating elements with Python module
    `xml.etree.cElementTree`

Where you can create a brand new .xml file.

I am stuck trying to figure  out how to set up the program.

My strategy is this:  Create all the level 1 nodes using a for loop and indexing the .csv, go through each line of the file and compare the current level and place the node at that level, then move on to the next line. If previous level nodes have been created, then move to next level nodes...and so on.

The end result should be:

```xml
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <level3>
                <level4>A<level4 />
                <level4>B<level4 />
            <level3 />
        <level2 />
    <level1 />
<root />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't try to go line-by-line through the csv file. Instead I would first try to put it all inside the most logical python data structures first and then proceed to manipulate it.

It seems to me that the most logical way to do this would be to make a list of dictionaries, where each line from the CSV is an element in the list as a dictionary. After that, loop through the list elements and do the xml-creation stuff( which I have no experience with, so if your problem is there, sorry)

If you could have a better example of your input CSV, maybe people could answer it better.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the libraries found here to do just that.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html
I was rusty and ignorant about xml and JSON when I posted the question, and now I have resolved this using those python libraries, namely using several for loops and iterating..  (xml and json)